# Android studio - can't manage to detect faces using OpenCV from pictures from my gallery

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to use opencv to detect faces in static pictures from my gallery but i can't manage to detect them (or draw rectangles on the picture). I have tried a lot of things, none of which worked for me. Help would be appreciated.

I have tried changing approaches to detecting the faces, none of which worked.

Logically everything seems fine I think: choose image from gallery ---> detectFaces function ---> setting height and width to each Mat i currently have, converting the imageView's image from bitmap to Mat, so i can work on the Mat to detect the faces and then later convert the Mat back to bitmap to see the results on the imageview (imgview.setImageBitmap(bm)).

```java
public class GalleryDetection extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private ImageView imgview;
private org.opencv.core.Mat rgba, grayscaleImage;
private CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier;
private int absoluteFaceSize, mDetectorType = 0;
private DetectionBasedTracker mNativeDetector;
private float mRelativeFaceSize = 0.2f;

static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) 
{
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                rgba = new Mat();
                grayscaleImage = new Mat();
                MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
                initializeOpenCVDependencies();
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void initializeOpenCVDependencies() {
    File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade frontalface.xml");
    cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
    mNativeDetector = new DetectionBasedTracker(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_detection);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    func();
}

void func() {
    this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
    this.imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewGallery);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String path = getPath(imageUri);
        imgview.setImageURI(imageUri);
        detectFaces();
    }
}

private void detectFaces() {
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imgview.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); // Convert imageview image to bitmap
    grayscaleImage = new Mat(bm.getHeight(), bm.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4); // grayImage same size as image view
    rgba = new Mat(imgview.getHeight(), imgview.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4); // rgbaImage same size as image view
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, rgba); // Convert bitmap to Mat
    absoluteFaceSize = (int) (bm.getHeight() * 0.2); // set the face size
    Utils.matToBitmap(drawRect(rgba), bm); // Convert the Mat with the triangle to bitmap
    imgview.setImageBitmap(bm); // Set the image in the imageview to the bitmap with the triangles
}

private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if(uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int col_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            return cursor.getString(col_index);
        }
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}

public Mat drawRect(Mat rgba) {
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB); // Convert colors (not really sure how and why it's here)
    if(absoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = grayscaleImage.rows();
        if(Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            absoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
        mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(absoluteFaceSize);
    }
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    if (mDetectorType == 0) {
        if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
            cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, faces, 1.1,2,2,
                    new Size(absoluteFaceSize, absoluteFaceSize), new Size());
        }
    }
    else if (mDetectorType == 1) {
        if (mNativeDetector != null) {
            mNativeDetector.detect(grayscaleImage, faces);
        }
    }
    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(rgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
    }
    return rgba;
}
```

}

Expected result: Image's faces are surrounded by rectangles

Actual result: Image showing without any rectangles

Answer (score 0):

[[image]][1[image: ]][After Doing this changes Working fine this code.

**I got  Image's faces are surrounded by rectangles**

**Note:-
1.In Android Studio, go to File > New > Import-Module  and the choose /sdk and wait for the sync to finish.
2.Do not import /sdk/java like most tutorials suggest.**

public class GalleryDetection extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final Scalar FACE_RECT_COLOR = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
private Button button, btnFaceDetect;
private ImageView imgview;
private AppCompatImageView imgview2;
private org.opencv.core.Mat rgba, grayscaleImage;
private CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier;
private int absoluteFaceSize = 0, mDetectorType = 0;
private float mRelativeFaceSize = 0.2f;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                rgba = new Mat();
                grayscaleImage = new Mat();
                initializeOpenCVDependencies();
                break;
            default:
                try {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void initializeOpenCVDependencies() {
    File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
    cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_detection);
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        try {
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    func();
}

void func() {
    this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngallery);
    this.btnFaceDetect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnselect);
    this.imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    this.imgview2 = findViewById(R.id.imageview2);

    btnFaceDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            detectFaces();
        }
    });


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            imgview2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            imgview.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private void detectFaces() {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
    dialog.show();
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imgview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();// Convert imageview image to bitmap
    grayscaleImage = new Mat(bm.getHeight(), bm.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4); // grayImage same size as image view
    rgba = new Mat(imgview2.getHeight(), imgview2.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4); // rgbaImage same size as image view
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, rgba); // Convert bitmap to Mat
    absoluteFaceSize = (int) (bm.getHeight() * 0.2); // set the face size
    Utils.matToBitmap(drawRect(rgba), bm);// Convert the Mat with the triangle to bitmap

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap pass = null;
            //Convert to byte array
            pass = bm;
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            pass.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            imgview2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
    // Set the image in the imageview to the bitmap with the triangles
}

public Mat drawRect(Mat rgba) {
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB); // Convert colors (not really sure how and why it's here)
    if (absoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = grayscaleImage.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            absoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
    }
    if (mDetectorType == 0) {
        if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
            MatOfRect feceDetection = new MatOfRect();
            cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(rgba, feceDetection, 1.1, 7, 2);
            for (Rect rect : feceDetection.toArray()) {
                Imgproc.rectangle(rgba, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                        new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                        FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3, 2);
            }
        }
    }
    return rgba;
}
```

}